# Nethack: Revive My Old Corpse?

Tags: nethack

So I've got this ghost attacking me... a little understandable, I am standing on his corpse, which is piled on his headstone.  Perhaps he doesn't like that!

But, I'd like to do him a favor, and put him back in his former body - well, I guess it's a favor.

I am a priest, but whenever I cast 'turn undead' the ghost either resists, or flees.  Does my level count for anything?

Answer (score 4):

The spell/wand "[turn undead](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Spellbook_of_turn_undead)" (not to be confused with the [`#turn`](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Turn_undead) command, which won't work for this) must be cast on the *corpse*, not the ghost, in order to revive it.

Comment: The OP apparently got a corpse by digging up a grave - which will just turn into a generic creature (probably human) if revived.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard: not true; the PC's corpse is found in the pile of his belongings under his ghost, although it may completely rot away before you reach it.

Comment: @Wooble My apologies then, I guess I have misremembered.

Answer (score -1):

The Wiki says you can, zap the corpse while the ghost is AWAKE (they are usually asleep--attack or chat usually works, they are light sleepers) and on/adjacent to corpse. If you like, try taming the ghost first for possible pet. Note, if it works the monster will be confused.  Also, check belongings for good stuff before reviving.